# Unity Check if Toggle isOn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am checking to see if a toggle is on. Normally I use `public Toggle myToggle` in the inspector but this this I am attaching the script to the `Toggle` and probably wrongly using `GetComponent<Toggle>()`

I get `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the `if(m_Toggle.isOn)` line.

This is the script attached to the `Toggle`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ToggleSound : MonoBehaviour {

    Toggle m_Toggle;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        m_Toggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
        Debug.Log(m_Toggle);

    }

    public ToggleSound ()
    {
        if(m_Toggle.isOn)
        {
            AudioManager.Instance.SetVolume(0, -80);
        }
        else
        {
            AudioManager.Instance.SetVolume(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious answer would be that `GetComponent<Toggle>()` does not find a Toggle instance. As you did not specify a instance to call it on, you call it as `this.GetComponent`. And the only Toggle in ToggleSound  is m_Toggle, currently not Initialized. If that would work, you could just use a bog standard class field to store the reference.

Comment: Why are you creating `public ToggleSound ()`? When do you want to check the if the toggle is on?

Comment: It is finging the correct instance alright. I am `Debug.Log(m_Toggle);` to be sure. The reason I have the `public ToggleSound ()` is I have it attached to the button click in the Toggle inspector to call when the toggle is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `public ToggleSound ()` into something like `public void ButtonClick()`.
In the inspector add this function in the `On Value Changed` box.

[image]

Comment: thanks for that. Was it because it was the same name as the class?

Comment: Yes, and you should also add `void` as you don't have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity select your object and set its `visible` property to true.

Comment: did think of that thanks. I learnt that the hard way before :-)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be that GetComponent() does not find a Toggle instance.

GetComponent has to be called on a instance of MonoBehavior. As you did not specify a instance to call it on, you currently call GetComponent onto the very instance of ToggleSound you are working with. Effectively you call `this.GetComponent`.

And the only Toggle in ToggleSound is m_Toggle, currently not Initialized. So the return value is set to the more sensible null. This is the programmer equivalent of wondering where your glasses are, while having it on your nose.

Comment: It seems to be finding alright. Here is the result of the `Debug` - `Toggle Sound (UnityEngine.UI.Toggle)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ToggleSound:Start() (at Assets/ToggleSound.cs:13)`

Comment: I take your point though as a general rule and I have updated my code to include `this.GetComponent`

Comment: @KeithPower My point was that this.GetComponent is propably going to be wrong. All it does it ask "what value does `m_Toggle` have?"